# Error al insertar en BD mysql con PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

estoy haciendo un insert  con PDO PHP a una base de datos mysql, le paso un arreglo para los parametros, pero funciona y me sale el siguiente error **SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined**

este es el metodo de conexion

```
public function conectar(){
    $conexion_mysql = "mysql:host=".$this->host.";dbname=".$this->base."";
    $conexionBD= new PDO($conexion_mysql,$this->usuario,$this->password);
    $conexionBD->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //esta linea arregla la codificacion de caracteres utf8
    $conexionBD->exec("set names utf8");

    return $conexionBD;
}
```

aqui esta el metodo donde se ejecuta la transacción

```
public function add(){
    $sql="INSERT INTO  PERSONAS 
                              (PA_PAIS_ID, 
                              PE_NOMBRE,
                              PE_CORREO,
                              PE_CLAVE,
                              PE_ESTADO)

                              VALUES(:PA_PAIS_ID,:PE_NOMBRE,:PE_CORREO,:PE_CLAVE,1)";
    $arreglo=array(":PE_PAIS_ID"=>1,":PE_NOMBRE"=>"Jose Miguel",":PE_CORREO"=>"josejara1996@gmail.com", ":PE_CLAVE"=>123);
    try {
          $db       = $this->conectar();
          $ejecutar = $db->prepare($sql);
          return $ejecutar->execute($arreglo);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';    


    }

}
```

ademas probe la consulta si tenia error de sintaxis pero no tiene, que puede ser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error en la siguiente linea;

```
VALUES(:PA_PAIS_ID,:PE_NOMBRE,:PE_CORREO,:PE_CLAVE,1)";
```

Tienes un `1` al final y este se acepta como un valor, puesto que deberias tenerla sin el `1`

Deberias tenerla asi;

```
 VALUES(:PA_PAIS_ID,:PE_NOMBRE,:PE_CORREO,:PE_CLAVE,:PE_ESTADO)";
```

De todos modos te falta ese valor en el array, si no mal interpreto querias colocar el `1` como valor, de todos modos puedes pasarlo en el array;

```
$arreglo=array(":PE_PAIS_ID"=>1,":PE_NOMBRE"=>"Jose Miguel",":PE_CORREO"=>"josejara1996@gmail.com", ":PE_CLAVE"=>123,":PE_ESTADO"=>"1");
```

Comment: si ahora funciona, una pregunta como puede obtener si la consulta se ejecuta correctamente

Comment: @josemigueljara el simple hecho de no tener una `excepcion` o error, es suficiente como para saber que esta todo correcto ya que tienes un bloque `try catch` ahora bien si quieres recibir algun mensaje pues en tu `return` lo puedes agregar en modo de confirmacion, digo yo...